# compile time null check not enough while iterating thorugh map keys

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

The `resultMap[element] + 1 ?? 0;` part is complaining that `resultMap[element]` might be null, suggesting me to use ! operator.Please suggest

```dart
class WordCount {
  Map<String, int> countWords(String wordle) {
    List<String> wordleCollections = wordle
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(RegExp(r",?[\s\t\n.,]"))
        .where((element) => element.isNotEmpty)
        .toList();
    var resultMap = <String, int>{};
    for (var element in wordleCollections) {
      resultMap[element] = resultMap[element] + 1 ?? 0;
    }

    return resultMap;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final wordCount = WordCount();
  print(wordCount.countWords("Joe can\'t tell between app, apple and a."));
}
```

Comment: Use `(resultMap[element] ?? 0) + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the the null-aware operator `??` imediately after the `resultMap[element]` access:

```dart
Map<String, int> countWords(String wordle) {
  List<String> wordleCollections = wordle
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(RegExp(r",?[\s\t\n.,]"))
      .where((element) => element.isNotEmpty)
      .toList();
  var resultMap = <String, int>{};
  for (var element in wordleCollections) {
    resultMap[element] = resultMap[element] ?? 0 + 1;
  }

  return resultMap;
}
```